# qt Pass vector between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

This is my first time using stack overflow. If I am not clear, I welcome your correction.
Recently, I used qt to write a waveform data processing project. I used many vectors to store different data and created several threads for different calculations and drawings. I completed vector transmission through qt's signal and slot mechanism. I think stack and heap do not have enough capacity to store, they should be directly stored in my memory, then the parameter of slot function is actually a data backup, do I need to manually release the parameter memory in the function? Or can I just pass a reference to the parameter? But from what I understand, it seems that qt's arguments cannot use reference types

What should I do in response to the above problems

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically you'll need to provide a [mre], with all the relevant code as copy-pasted text. BTW - the stack is typically quite small, but the heap isn't.

Comment: Remember that all threads in a single process shares the same memory. So unless the threads need to work on the same data simultaneously just pass around pointers or references to the vectors. Then you only have a single vector object, and a single set of data stored in the vector.

Comment: vector does the heap management for you, so you don't need to manually release anything. But without a minimal example, we can only tell you what is not the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I know what I should do

Answer (score 1):

QT's QVector class is marked as ["implicitly shared"](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/shared.html). This means that copies are — behind the scenes — just references to the storage of the original object and thus very cheap to make. As long as you do not make changes to the vector in either sender or receiver (beyond letting it go out of scope), this property will hold and you do not have to worry about the cost of copying the vector.